# in SQL, how can I find duplicate string values within the same record?

Tags: sql

Sample table

```
Record Number  |   Filter  | Filters_Applied
----------------------------------------------
       1       |    yes    | red, blue
       2       |    yes    | green
       3       |    no     |       
       4       |    yes    | red, red, blue
```

Is it possible to query all records where there are duplicate string values? For example, how could I query to pull record 4 where the string "red" appeared twice? Except in the table that I am dealing with, there are far more string values that can populate in the "filters_applied" column.

**CLARIFICATION** I am working out of Periscope and pulling data using SQL.

Comment: is there a chance where the `filter applied` will appear as `red, blue, red`?

Comment: You should not store CSV data.  This will be very difficult/impossible depending on which database you are using.  Which database are you using?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu yes-- no specific order

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this is not CSV data, this was just an example of the basic layout of the table

Comment: `red, red, blue` <-- then what is this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen apologies, I was thinking "csv downloads" from an excel spreadsheet... it is just now occurring to me what the heck "csv" means lol but thanks for the learning opportunity good sir. 

either way, I am trying to figure out the query and am not worried how the database is set up

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  Your question probably cannot be answered using SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have to check that in the logical page.
You can query the table with like '%red%'.

> select Filters_Applied from table where Filters_Applied like '%red%';

You will get the data which has red at least one. Then, doing some string analysis in logic page.

In php, You can use the substr_count function to determine the number of occurrences of the string.

```
//the loop to load db query
while(){
  $number= substr_count("Filters_Applied",red); 
  if($number>1){
    echo "this".$Filters_Applied.">1"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for `SQL-SERVER` or other versions which can run these functions

Apply this logic

```
declare @val varchar(100) = 'yellow,blue,white,green'
DECLARE @find varchar(100) = 'green'

select @val = replace(@val,' ','') -- remove spaces

select @val;

select (len(@val)-len(replace(@val,@find,'')))/len(@find) [recurrence]
```

Comment: This will fail if a color happens to be a substring of another color.

Comment: Correct... just looking for an example

Comment: If the OP changes then I change the solution

Answer (score 0):

Create this Function which will parse string into rows and write query as given below.  This will works for SQL Server.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[StrParse]
            (@delimiter CHAR(1),  
            @csv       NTEXT)  
RETURNS @tbl TABLE(Keys  NVARCHAR(255))  
AS  

BEGIN  
DECLARE  @len INT  
SET @len = Datalength(@csv)  
IF NOT @len > 0  
    RETURN  

DECLARE  @l INT  
DECLARE  @m INT  

SET @l = 0  
SET @m = 0  

DECLARE  @s VARCHAR(255)  
DECLARE  @slen INT  

WHILE @l <= @len  
    BEGIN  

    SET @l = @m + 1--current position  
    SET @m = Charindex(@delimiter,Substring(@csv,@l + 1,255))--next delimiter or 0  

    IF @m <> 0  
        SET @m = @m + @l  
    --insert @tbl(keys) values(@m)  
    SELECT @slen = CASE   
                        WHEN @m = 0 THEN 255 --returns the remainder of the string  
                        ELSE @m - @l  
                    END --returns number of characters up to next delimiter  

    IF @slen > 0  
        BEGIN  
        SET @s = Substring(@csv,@l,@slen)  
        INSERT INTO @tbl  
                    (Keys)  
        SELECT @s  
        END  

    SELECT @l = CASE   
                    WHEN @m = 0 THEN @len + 1 --breaks the loop  
                    ELSE @m + 1  
                END --sets current position to 1 after next delimiter  
    END  

RETURN  
END

GO

CREATE TABLE Table1# (RecordNumber int, [Filter] varchar(5), Filters_Applied varchar(100))
GO
INSERT INTO Table1# VALUES
(1,'yes','red, blue')
,(2,'yes','green')
,(3,'no ','') 
,(4,'yes','red, red, blue')

GO
--This query will return what you are expecting
SELECT t.RecordNumber,[Filter],Filters_Applied,ltrim(rtrim(keys)), count(*)NumberOfRows
FROM Table1# t
CROSS APPLY dbo.StrParse (',', t.Filters_Applied)
GROUP BY t.RecordNumber,[Filter],Filters_Applied,ltrim(rtrim(keys)) HAVING count(*) >1
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state your DBMS, but in Postgres this isn't that complicated:

```
select st.*
from sample_table st
  join lateral (
    select count(*) <> count(distinct trim(item)) as has_duplicates
    from unnest(string_to_array(filters_applied,',')) as t(item)    
  ) x on true
where x.has_duplicates;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/TJUGJ44586

---

<sup>With the exception of `string_to_array()` the above is actually standard SQL</sup>